# How to have a class automatically applied to all new LI elements inside a UL?

Tags: jquery

With jQuery's event delegation (http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation), I am able to have events automatically attached to LI elements which are added to a UL, as shown in the follow code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Betum

But how do I have styles automatically added as well?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("ul#list").append('<li>added before</li>');

        //assures that any new LI added to LIST will have this click event
        $("ul#list").on("click","li", function() {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        });

        //how to also assure that any LI added to LIST will have this style
        $("ul#list li").addClass("original");

        $("ul#list").append('<li>added after</li>');
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        li.original {
            color: red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        li.selected {
            color:green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <ul id="list">
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
            <li>four</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: .clone( true, true ) copies data (styles, attributes, etc) and events.

Comment: The event handlers are not automagically bound to the added elements. Instead a single handler is bound to an ancestor element (or `document` itself), and the event will bubble from the added elements up to the ancestor. There is no such mechanism to dynamically expose classes and styles.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple. Apply a single class to the `<ul>` and write your CSS based on that, not relying on any particular classes on the `<li>`s. For example:

```
ul.someClass > li {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

No extra JavaScript required.

Comment: yes, I can do that but then the "color" attribute of my class doesn't override the original value: http://jsfiddle.net/3eYyD/

Answer (score 0):

## Adding the class

You can add the class to the newly created element with `.addClass()`

```
$("ul#list").append($('<li>added after</li>').addClass("original"));
```

Or just write it manually when you create the element:

```
$("ul#list").append('<li class="original">added after</li>');
```

[<kbd>jsFiddleDemo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Betum/3/)

---

## Alternative: Making the CSS Selector more general

You can also use the `original` class as the default class for all list items inside the ul.

```
li {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li.selected {
    color:green;
}
```

[<kbd>jsFiddleDemo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Betum/5/)